# How is this react controlled component input's value updated when no props are passed

Tags: reactjs

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/5nzpxyuu/6/) which shows an Input component that I have created:

```
const Input = ({
  onChange = () => {},
  invalid,
  type = 'text',
  placeholder = '',
  className,
  value,
  ...rest
}) =>
  <input
    onChange={onChange}
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    autoComplete="off"
    value={value}
    {...rest}
  />;

Input.displayName = 'Input';
```

In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/5nzpxyuu/6/), I have not hooked up any props:

```
const MyComponent = function(props){
    return <div><Input /></div>;
};
```

But when I type text into the input, the value of the input changes even though I am not passing a `value` prop or a `onChange` handler into the component.

Is my input not a controlled input somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `Input` component is that if you pass a value prop and do not pass the `onChange` prop which in your input is then assigned by default, you will end up with a static value and will no longer be able to change the value. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5nzpxyuu/7/)**

It works in the current state because it is treated an uncontrolled input since the value attribute is undefined.

I will rather recommend you to pass the props and have a `propType` validation on your input for the `required onChange and value prop`

```
const Input = ({
  onChange = () => {},
  invalid,
  type = 'text',
  placeholder = '',
  className,
  value,
  ...rest
}) =>
  <input
    onChange={onChange}
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    autoComplete="off"
    value={value}
    {...rest}
  />;

Input.displayName = 'Input';

Input.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is uncontrolled because of:

```
value = { value }    //value = undefined
```

Since value is undefined so the field will become uncontrolled, to verify that use this:

`value = {undefined}`

it will behave in the same way.

Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/5nzpxyuu/6/)**.

Comment: Should I set value to a default value?  E.g. value = ''

Comment: if you set the value as `value=''` then it will become read-only because value will always be `''`

Comment: I mean as a defaultProp

Comment: ohh, yes set the default values.